# Left Join query return bad results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, laravel

I've been trying for hours to make a left join query with MySQL.
I've a table called "at_friends" where I store the relationships between users.

```
id  |  id_user1 |  id_user2  |  accepted
1   |  2        |  1         |  1
2   |  1        |  3         |  0
```

It means that user 1 is friend with user 2, and user 1 sent a friend request to user 3.

And here is my table "at_users"

```
id  |  name
1   |  "John"   
2   |  "Mike"   
3   |  "Bob"
```

I've tried this query :

```
SELECT at_users.id, at_users.name
    FROM at_users 
    LEFT JOIN at_friends
         ON at_friends.id_user1 = at_users.id
         OR at_friends.id_user2 = at_users.id
         AND at_friends.accepted = 1
    WHERE id_user1 = 1 OR id_user2 = 1
```

"1" is the unique id of the current user (John)

But I get these results

```
id  |  name
1   |  "John"   
2   |  "Mike"   
1   |  "John"
```

What I'm trying to have is the list of the accepted friends of the user n°1.

By the way, I use Laravel, but I don't know if there is a way to do this without a custom mysql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM at_users u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_user2 AS friendID FROM at_friends WHERE id_user1 = 1 AND accepted = 1
            UNION 
            SELECT id_user1 AS friendID FROM at_friends WHERE id_user2 = 1 AND accepted = 1
           ) AS A ON u.id = A.friendID
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that only requires a single scan of the friends table:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM at_users u 
JOIN at_friends f
  ON 1 in (f.id_user1, f.id_user2) and
     u.id = case f.id_user1 when 1 then id_user2 else id_user1 end and 
     f.accepted=1
```

[SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae1acd/4)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has an accepted answer but I wanted to add this...

#### There is a Laravel way!

Add this helper method to your `User` model

```
public function friends(){
    $id = $this->id;
    return $this->join('at_friends', function($q) use ($id){
        $q->on('at_friends.id_user2', '=', 'users.id');
        $q->where('at_friends.id_user1', '=', $id);
        $q->orOn('at_friends.id_user1', '=', 'users.id');
        $q->where('at_friends.id_user2', '=', $id);
    });
}
```

Here's how you can then use it

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->friends()->where('accepted', true)->get();
```

If you want to you can ever add this attribute accessor to the model:

```
public function getFriendsAttribute(){
    return $this->friends()->where('accepted', true)->get();
}
```

And use it like that:

```
$user->friends;
```

Comment: Well... that's great ! I'll try this ASAP and give you feedback ! Thanks !